# Not able to add a library to android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

Uber offers the following libraries, but I dont know how to add them to my Android Studio project:

https://github.com/uber/RIBs/tree/main/android

The link above has a Libraries folder, I need to add that to my project

I tried to configure my gradle but that did not work. Can somone give me some insight on how to do this?

Comment: Did you try [following the documentation](https://github.com/uber/RIBs#installation-for-android)?

Comment: yes I tried that, but it didnt give me any errors, but when I tried to add the rootActivity.java, it was showing a lot of dependencies issue., so it didnt work

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to include those dependency error message into your post? In general it is a bad idea to write something like "but that did not work" and don't describe in detail what that means. How do you think we can help you if you don't describe the problem?